# Magento 2 Upgrade from 2.1.6 to 2.2.4 - Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=40252

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I was upgrading **Magento 2.1.6** to **Magento 2.2.4**. Everything went ok but the final step is to run `bin/magento setup: upgrade` and when I run that I get the below error.

[image]

```
ERROR :  Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=40252 in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
```

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Warning-Error-while-sending-QUERY-packet/td-p/88511

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the wait_timeout and max_allowed_packet value from your database configuration...

increase wait_timeout = XX to wait_timeout=180

Also, Change at least max_allowed_packet = 512M or 1024M